# Issues with image hotspot mapping and popup position onmouse over

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, onmouseover

For the life of me I can not seem to get a popup image to display onMouseOver at the location of the hotspot. The images seem to float to the top of the page when content is added above the div. The follow is what I have that consists of a multiple snippets. I corrected the hotspot resize using imageMapResizer.min.js, don't think that is causing a conflict.

```js
    function ShowImage(src)
    {
        var img = document.getElementById('popupImage');
        var div = document.getElementById('popup');
        img.src = src;
    }
    function HideImage()
    {
        document.getElementById('popup').style.display = "none";
    }
function pop(e) { //function called by first hotspot
    var thing = document.getElementById("popup");

    thing.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
    thing.style.top = e.clientY  + 'px';
    $("#popup").toggle();

    return true;
 }
```

```css
.popup {
  position:absolute;
        z-index:20000;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
        display:inherit;
  background-color:#FFF;
  border: 0px solid;
}
```

```html
<div align="center">
<img name="usaMap" src="images/clientlogo4.png" usemap="#m_usaMap" border="0" width="800px">
<map name="m_usaMap">
        <area shape="poly" coords="33,19,38,93,163,90,161,31" HREF="#" title="Farmboy" onMouseOver="pop(event); javascript:ShowImage('images/1.jpg')"  onMouseOut="pop(event); javascript:HideImage()" \>
  </map>
  </div>

<div id="popup" class="popup"><img NAME="popup1" id="popup1" src="" alt="" /> 
<div id="popup" class="pop-up">
   <img id="popupImage" alt="Popup image" /> 
</div>
```

Comment: solved my own issue. cleaned up javascript  code, div container to display popup image and positioned the div to fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The following is the fix. I will continue to try and clean the code, onMouseOut looks sloppy. Slowly learning.

```js
function pop(e,src) { 
        var thing = document.getElementById("popup");
        var img = document.getElementById('popupImage');
        var div = document.getElementById('popup');
        img.src = src;
    thing.style.top = e.clientY  + 'px';
 thing.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
 
    $("#popup").toggle();

    return true;
 }
```

```css
.popup {
  position:absolute;
        z-index:20000;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
        display:none;
  background-color:#FFF;
  border: 0px solid;
}
```

```html
<div align="center" style="position:relative;">
<img name="usaMap" src="images/clientlogo4.png" usemap="#m_usaMap" border="0" width="800px">
<map name="m_usaMap">
        <area shape="poly" coords="33,19,38,93,163,90,161,31" HREF="#" title="Farmboy" onMouseOver="pop(event,'images/1.jpg')"  onMouseOut="pop(event); javascript:HideImage()" \>
  </map
  <div id="popup" class="popup" style="position:fixed;">
   <img id="popupImage" alt="Popup image" /> 
</div> 
</div>
```